# In JavaScript, manually controlling order of event listeners

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

Assuming that FORM contains INPUT, have the following listeners:

#### JavaScript

```
function formFirst(e) { ... }
function formLast(e) { ... }
function inputFirst(e) { ... }
function inputLast(e) { ... }
function middle(e) { ... }

document.getElementById('form').addEventListener('change',formFirst,true);
document.getElementById('form').addEventListener('change',formLast,false);
document.getElementById('input').addEventListener('change',inputFirst,true);
document.getElementById('input').addEventListener('change',inputLast,false);
```

#### Desired order of firing

```
formFirst()   // normal - outer element, useCapture = true
inputFirst()  // normal - triggering element, declared first
middle()      // -- how to do this?
inputLast()   // normal - triggering element, declared second
formLast()    // normal - outer element, useCapture = false
```

#### Nature of problem and attempted solutions

Own code at FORM level, `formFirst`, `formLast` and `middle`, but have no access to INPUT code, `inputFirst` and `inputLast` - although could add own listeners on the INPUT.

**Attempt 1** modify `formFirst()` to create and dispatch a  new `change Event` (would be ignored within `formFirst`) that would call `inputFirst()`, but have no way of stopping propagation to prevent `inputLast()` being called subsequently.

**Attempt 2** add `middle` added as listener to INPUT, but cannot guarantee firing order of two listeners of same type and same useCapture.

---

Premise of Attempt 2 is incorrect - firing order is determined by declaration order within the target Element.

#### Here are the rules

1. non-target Element triggers with `useCapture=false`, starting at the outermost Element and working toward the target Element

   a) if more than one `useCapture=true` triggers for same element, then order of declaration.
2. at target Element, order of declaration, *regardless of `useCapture`*
3. non-target Element triggers with `useCapture=false`, starting at the innermost Element and working away from the target Element

   a) if more than one `useCapture=false` triggers for same Element, then order of declaration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that [this](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html) answers just your question. feel free to comment\contact me for more info.

----- edit ------

OK, I just played with it a little as promised, and I found a very simple solution:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function formFirst(e) { alert(1); }
function formLast(e) { alert(5); }
function inputFirst(e) { alert(2); }
function inputLast(e) { alert(4); }
function middle(e) { alert(3); }

function init(){
    document.getElementById('form').addEventListener('change',formFirst,true);
    document.getElementById('form').addEventListener('change',formLast,false);
    document.getElementById('input').addEventListener('change',inputFirst,true);
    document.getElementById('input').addEventListener('change',middle,true);
      /*** alternative to last tow lines  
    document.getElementById('input').addEventListener('change',function(){inputFirst();middle();},true);
         **/
    document.getElementById('input').addEventListener('change',inputLast,false);
}

</script>
<body onload="init();">
<form id="form">
<input type="text" id="input" /> <br />
</form>
</body>
```

notice:

- I put the addEventListener part into an init function, so I can call it after the page is loaded and the element are already exist.
- I have run this just on chrome. So I don't want to guarantee you things about other browsers.
- An alternative is writing the event handling on your own. here is an example for that. relaying on [this](http://stikiflem.wordpress.com/2008/09/10/create-custom-events-in-javascript/) article.

  ```
  <script type="text/javascript">

  function formFirst(e) { alert(1); }
  function formLast(e) { alert(5); }
  function inputFirst(e) { alert(2); }
  function inputLast(e) { alert(4); }
  function middle(e) { alert(3); }

  function init(){

    //create event
    myHandler = new Event();

    //add handler
    myHandler.addHandler(formFirst);
    myHandler.addHandler(inputFirst);
    myHandler.addHandler(middle);
    myHandler.addHandler(inputLast);
    myHandler.addHandler(formLast);

    //regiser one listener on some object
    document.getElementById('input').addEventListener('change',function(){myHandler.execute();},true);
  }


  function Event(){
    this.eventHandlers = new Array();
  }

  Event.prototype.addHandler = function(eventHandler){
    this.eventHandlers.push(eventHandler);
  }

  Event.prototype.execute = function(){
    for(var i = 0; i < this.eventHandlers.length; i++){
      this.eventHandlers[i]();
    }
  }


  </script>
  <body onload="init();">
  <form id="form">
  <input type="text" id="input" /> <br />
  </form>
  </body>
  ```

Comment: for your specific example, just use 'ture' as the third parameter to all your event listeners.

Comment: from my testing I think you are incorrect.  if `formLast` were added with `useCapture = true`, then `formLast` would fire _before_ the INPUT triggers, not follow them as it does now.

Comment: You are right. I didn't think it throw. Try [this article](http://stikiflem.wordpress.com/2008/09/10/create-custom-events-in-javascript/), there you can create your own handlers. And I have not tried it (just found it). But I guess you can attach the middle function as to the event handler that fires the `inputFirst` function so that handler will later fire the middle method. I'll play with that option at the evening. So let me know if that still doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry about taking so long to get back - moving.  You are right - order of creating listeners determines order of firing within the _target_ - although it makes sense that `true` triggers should fire before `false`, as on non-target, this is not the case.

Comment: Hi again. A few days ago i read something about jQuery, Its not what you want but could help. because there is an `callback` option. which means that you call one method and in the callback you send the next one (creating an execution chain). Could be problematic if somehow tow fields like that trigger simultaneously. But on the `change` event i doubt that.